# .NET 3.5 .NET 4 errors in the setup project dependents

Tags: .net, visual-studio, setup-project

Added .NET3.5 , .NET4 to project dependents, then selected "Download from local", without web.

Got strange errors on building setup project :

> Error 10  Unrecoverable build
>   error D:...\Setup\Setup.vdproj   Setup
>
> Error 7   The install location for
>   prerequisites has not been set to
>   'component vendor's web site' and the
>   file
>   'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64ru.exe'
>   in item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4
>   (x86 and x64)' can not be located on
>   disk. See Help for more
>   information.  D:....\Setup\Setup.vdproj  Setup
>
> Error 5   The install location for
>   prerequisites has not been set to
>   'component vendor's web site' and the
>   file
>   'DotNetFx35Client\DotNetFx35ClientSetup.exe'
>   in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client
>   Profile' can not be located on disk.
>   See Help for more
>   information.  D:...\Setup\Setup.vdproj   Setup
>
> Error 9   General failure building
>   bootstrapper  D:....\Setup\Setup.vdproj  Setup

What it means ? How it happened ? How to fix it ?

thank you.

Comment: Did you select "Download prerequisite from the following location" option and browse to your prerequisite file?

Comment: Not, I picked "Download from same location as my Application"

Comment: Try using "Download prerequisite from the following location" and browse to your prerequisite file.

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu but it's adding this files to setup folder but shows this errors. Download prerequisite from the following location is not the same, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" option, the prerequisite is retrieved from it's original location (in Program Files).

However, this works only if the prerequisite package exists. If the package doesn't exist, you need to either download it from the vendor's website or manually set the location.

If you still want to use the same location as your application, you need to modify the prerequisite information and make sure that its package is present on your machine. Perhaps this will help: http://danycxxx.blogspot.com/2009/09/download-prerequisites-from-same.html

Comment: I need to specify .NET 35, 4 for my locale somehow.